# Finding the Bernoulli distribution using its characteristic function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have managed to calculate that the characteristic function for the Bernoulli distribution is equal to

$\phi(t)=(pe^{it}+1-p)^n$

But now I'd like to derive the Bernoulli distribution using this result. I have found the following formula to do it:

$p_X(k)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ikt}\phi(t)dt$

This integral is pretty awful after inserting the Bernoulli distribution into it. I have noticed that after removing $2\pi$ and the integral sign with $dt$ I will get what I need, but I don't think this is the right way of doing that. How to find the Bernoulli distribution using its characteristic function?

Comment: Here is a link to the inversion formula of characteristic function. https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/characteristic.pdf

Comment: Since there is a 1 to 1 correspondence between Borel probability measures and characteristic functions, you don't need the inversion formula. You calculate the char function using the pmf of Bernoulli and you're done

Answer (score 2):

In the terminology I learned, that's the characteristic function of the Binomial distribution; Bernoulli is the special case $n=1$. Note that$$\begin{align}\phi(t)&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(1-p)^{n-k}p^ke^{ikt}\\\implies P(X=k)&=\binom{n}{k}(1-p)^{n-k}p^k[0\le k\le n\land k\in\Bbb Z].\end{align}$$Since the distribution is discrete, you can only use an integral to obtain it if you're proficient in the [Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), viz.$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i(k^\prime-k)t}dt=\delta(k^\prime-k).$$